# Azure Face API not working for Bae64 String,Local File URL,Native File Url

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

### **Need Simple Face Detection / Verification Process**

Existing One:

- Need to capture image and then send it to web server to make it as URL
- After that need to get generated URL and send it to `FACE DETECT API` to generate FACE ID
- On successful attempt we will get a `FACE ID` for the uploaded image in response
- Then need to call `FACE VERIFY API` with two `FACE ID`'s (Already Stored FACE ID,FACE ID from response) for verification
- On success will get the result whether the images are same or not

Cons faced while using on Mobile Devices:

- This process takes time and completely depends on Internet Speed (ie. In India even in Cities there is not enough Internet Speed then think about villages)
- It doesn't support `BASE64` encoded image or local `FILE URI`
- Time is precious, Small delay leads to lack of interest in product

Suggestion:

- Assume that Person's face data is already registered in Azure face containers and the `FACE ID` is stored in some database
- Need to just capture image and send it to `FACE VERIFY API`

  Parameters:

  ```
  1. Person's registered `Face ID`
  2. Captured image formats BASE64, Local File URL,Native File URL, exsisting URL
  3. ........
  ```
- It will return the result whether it is same or different

Most of the users are expecting these features, It will be very efficient to use if the suggestion is implemented in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial assertion was not correct: you don't need to send the image to a web server to host it before calling face API.

Face API 'detect' operation accepts binary data as input, so you could directly call it with your image content and you're done. See documentation [here](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236), which states:

> Request body
>
> To detect in a URL (or binary data) specified image.

Side note: I agree on the fact that you still have to send the image payload and it's slower than detecting in local